Is it possible to load a YOLO model on GPU once and give it to multiple Python processes?
I'm working on performing object detection on multiple videos/streams simultaneously using a YOLO model. I set up the processing of multiple videos using the built-in multiprocessing library in Python.
Problem I'm facing is that for each process, the model is initialized again and again. So if I run 4 videos, the model will be initialized four times. The issue is, each initialization takes around 400 MB of GPU memory, and each inference also takes around 400 MB. So 4 videos would take around 3200 MB of GPU memory. Even with having a top-of-the-line RTX 4090, the 24 GB memory is filled up quickly with around 22 streams.
What I'm trying to do is for the YOLO model to be initialized ONCE (400 MB) and then this model be used by each process for each video/stream for inference (400 MB). So inference for 10 videos would be 10*400 = 4000 MB + 400 MB (for the model initialization) = 4400 MB of GPU memory.
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm running:
from ultralytics import YOLO
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count
from configs.config import yolo_model_path


def read_streams(stream_url):
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url)

    logger.info("Streaming has been started..")

    while True:
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        
        return frame


def process_streams(stream_links, model_path):
    model = YOLO(model_path)
    while True:
        frame = read_streams(stream_links)

        if frame is None:
            break

        resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (frame_size, frame_size))
        results = model.predict(frame)
        
        # performs some logic on the frame and results


def main(model_path, stream_urls, testing=False):
    processes = []
    for stream in stream_urls:
        p = Process(
            target=process_streams,
            args=(stream, model_path),
        )

        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stream_urls = ['rtsp://url1', 'rtsp://url2']

    main(yolo_model_path, stream_urls)

I tried setting up the model globally like this:
from ultralytics import YOLO
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count
from configs.config import yolo_model_path

model = Detector(yolo_model_path)

def read_streams(stream_url):
...

But I get the following error:
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/test/Desktop/LSM/src/atm/main.py", line 52, in get_multiple_streams
    results = detector.model_detector(resized_frame)
  File "/home/test/Desktop/LSM/src/atm/../atm/detections.py", line 14, in model_detector
    return self.model.predict(frame)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/model.py", line 445, in predict
    self.predictor.setup_model(model=self.model, verbose=is_cli)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/predictor.py", line 297, in setup_model
    self.model = AutoBackend(
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/nn/autobackend.py", line 142, in __init__
    model = weights.to(device)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1152, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/nn/tasks.py", line 232, in _apply
    self = super()._apply(fn)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 802, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 802, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 802, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 825, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1150, in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 288, in _lazy_init
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method

To solve this, I include this line at the top of my script:
from multiprocessing import set_start_method
set_start_method('spawn')

Which further gives the error:
RuntimeError: context has already been set
Which is finally solved by:
set_start_method('spawn', force=True)
Now the code does run, but my problem isn't solved, in fact it is worsened. Running on two videos, the output for the GPU memory should show 400 MB for the initialization, and 400MB + 400MB for the inference on both of them.
Instead its this:
test@gpu:~/Desktop/LSM/src/atm$ nvidia-smi
Mon Jun 10 19:45:01 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.171.04             Driver Version: 535.171.04   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090        Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  Off |
|  0%   41C    P2              69W / 450W |   2512MiB / 24564MiB |     12%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1606      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          203MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1914      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         50MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3582      G   ...erProcess --variations-seed-version      111MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4387      G   ...irefox/3836/usr/lib/firefox/firefox       14MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    125205      C   python3                                     416MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    125298      C   /usr/bin/python3                            842MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    125299      C   /usr/bin/python3                            842MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Looking at the last two processes, each process is taking up around 400 MB for the initialization and 400 MB for the inference (approx 800MB in total). On top of that there is also 400 MB separately being taken for nothing.
Sorry for the essay but any help would be appreciated.

If you are considering multiple image streams, consider working with a model server. Reference - https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/13673
